# How to call this function 15 times by for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call this function 15 times by for loop that is fire on button click Please help me.

```
$(function()
{
    $("#btnSave").click(function()
    {
        html2canvas($("$widget"),
        {
            onrendered: function(canvas)
            {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                //Convert and download as image
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);
                //Clean up
                //document.body.removeChild(canvas)
            }
    });
    });
});
```

I want to call this function 15 times by for loop that is fire on button click Please help me . Please

Comment: Ok, but first can you help us by taking that code and putting it in the question?

Comment: Which function?? html2canvas or onrendered???

Comment: @ AmmarCSE  i put code in comment bcz stackoverflow show some formating issue in posting . I posted the code in comment that is in img

Comment: Please update your question with your code, not by a screenshot, but by literals.

Comment: Why would you want to call it 15 times???

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btnSave").click(function(){

    var counter = 15;

    while(counter > 0) {
        html2canvas($("#widget"), {
                    onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    theCanvas = canvas;
                    document.body.appendChild(canvas); 
                    // Convert and download as image Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); $("#img-out").append(canvas); 
                    // Clean up //document.body.removeChild(canvas); 
                } 
        }); 

        counter--;

    }


});
```

Comment: $(function() 
{ 
    $("#btnSave").click(function() 
 { 
        html2canvas($("#widget"), 
  {
            onrendered: function(canvas)
   {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                // Convert and download as image 
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);
                // Clean up 
                //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
});

Comment: please do this in above commented code . I am very new in js . please help me ...

Comment: I really don't understand the purpose of calling it 15 times? Can someone explain?

Comment: Well, with the code snippet being a subset of the application, it will be inappropriate to comment on the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple for loop to repeat the code, but I recommend being more explicit and using the excellent Lodash library if you can:

https://lodash.com/docs#times

```
_.times(15, function() {
    // this function body will run 15 times
});
```

Comment: Just to add another alternative, ***with underscore.js*** you can make it `_(15).times(function(n){ /* do something */ });` -- looks pretty close to Ruby-style.

Answer (score 0):

This will call the function that results from clicking the button, 15 times.

```
for(var i = 0; i<15; i++)
{
     $("#btnSave").click();
}
```

You can either add this directly below the code you're talking about, or you can run this code in the console (Copy>right click in web browser>Inspect Element>Console>Paste>Enter).